# Lambda Expressions

Tags: c, lambda

Can somebody explain me lambda expressions & what they can be used for. I have googled for it & have a rough idea. most of the examples give c# code. How about lambda expressions in plain old C...?

Comment: Following el.pescado below, since C is very definitely an imperative language creation of anonymous method (function) isn't done. The closest C comes to anonymous functions is through function pointers like the comparator function pointer passed to `qsort(3)` (but they aren't really anonymous as they need to be defined and thus named).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are actually two things called "lambda expressions", which are rather loosely related:

1. Lambda expressions are fundamental part of [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and are closely related to functional programming
2. In imperative languages, lambda expressions are usually synonyms for anonymous methods. In C#, for example you can pass lambda expression (ie. an expression itself, not just its result) as an argument:

C#:

```
someCollection.Apply (x => 2*x); // apply expression to every object in collection
// equivalent to 
someCollection.Apply (delegate (int x) { return 2 * X; });
```

Having said that, C does not support anonymous methods. You can, however, use function pointers to achieve similar results:

```
int multiply (int x)
{
    return 2 * x;
}

...
collection_apply (some_collection, multiply);
```

Comment: Allegedly, Apple have added something to LLVM to add a kind of lambda expression to C (code blocks or sth). Not an official standard, though, and I have forgotten the exact search terms.

Comment: Code blocks are part of Objective-C (which Apple uses for most of its higher level libraries), which is C with an added OO syntax.

Answer (score 2):

el.pescado's answer is right but the example that he provides has an easy work around, using a function pointer.  Many uses of lambda functions can't be solved with c's function pointers.

Say you write these functions in c:

```
int Multiply_1(int x) { return(x*1); }
int Multiply_2(int x) { return(x*2); }
int Multiply_3(int x) { return(x*3); }
int Multiply_4(int x) { return(x*4); }
etcetera, to infinity
```

Those are all pretty easy to understand.  Now assume that you want to write a function that takes y as input and returns a pointer to the function Multiply_y():

```
(int)(int) *Make_Multiplier(int y) { return(Multiply_y); }
```

Where "Multiply_y" is a dynamically created function of the form of Multiply_1, Multiply_2, etc.  Languages that have first-class lambda functions can do that.

Comment: I'm saying that it doesn't work in c.  el.pescado made a very simple lambda but to make a more complicated one is not possible.

Comment: sorry its not that clear if you read only this answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't support lamba expressions...if you know perl, I highly recommend the book "higher order perl" which will give you a great introduction to all sorts of functional programming techniques in a familiar (if you know perl) and practical setting.

Answer (score -1):

Look here on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx)

Comment: I guessed that he meant C++ not C.  Fair assumption I thought.