# lambda expression question

Tags: c#, lambda

Browsing the Moq code, I saw this bit of code.  I'm hoping someone can explain what is happening in the call to Guard.NotNull as shown here.  This is from ExtensionExpression.cs, in case anyone is wondering

```
public static LambdaExpression ToLambda(this Expression expression)
{
    Guard.NotNull(() => expression, expression);
    /* other code suppressed...
```

---

```
/* code from Guard.cs */
internal static class Guard
{
/// <summary>
/// Ensures the given <paramref name="value"/> is not null.
/// Throws <see cref="ArgumentNullException"/> otherwise.
/// </summary>
public static void NotNull<T>(Expression<Func<T>> reference, T value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(GetParameterName(reference));
    }
}
/* rest of code suppressed */
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lambda Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694756/lambda-expressions)

Comment: @Talljoe: this is a quite specific question about the lambda expression in a piece of code, and really isn't a duplicate of a general "what's lambda?" question.

Answer (score 3):

All it is doing is to return the name of the argument in the exception rather than having it hard coded when the value is null. In the case of Moq the name of the argument most likely comes from the test itself so it would be hard to hard code it in the Moq code.

Expressions can capture the information about the method/property such as its name.